# Blazor Compiler Error CS1061 - Report has no definition for Title

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

in my blazor project I have two applications (Server, Client, Shared).
Now I'm stuck for hours, because in my Report.razor page the IDE shows error CS1061. I can't resolve any property from the Report List with Report objects.

Does anyone have inputs to fix my problem? Thank you!

Server application: **ReportController.cs**

```
using BlazorApp.Shared;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.Resource;

namespace BlazorApp.Server.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
    public class ReportController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ILogger<ReportController> _logger;

        public ReportController(ILogger<ReportController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        private List<Report> Reports = new()
        {
            new("Title","Desc","Name","Lastname")
        };

        [HttpGet("List")]
        public ActionResult List()
        {
            return Ok(Reports);
        }
    }
}
```

Client application: **Report.razor**

```
@page "/reports"
@using BlazorApp.Shared
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
@attribute [Authorize]
@inject HttpClient Http

<PageTitle>Report</PageTitle>

<h1>Report</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var report in Reports)
    {
        <li>@report.Title</li> -> Compiler Error CS1061
    }
</ul>

@code {

    private List<Report> Reports = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Reports = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Report>>("List/Report");
    }
}
```

My Shared class: **Report.cs**

```
namespace BlazorApp.Shared
{
    public class Report
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string ReporterName { get; set; }

        public string ReporterLastname { get; set; }

        public Report() { }

        public Report(string title, string description, string reporterName, string reporterLastname)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Description = description;
            this.ReporterName = reporterName;
            this.ReporterLastname = reporterLastname;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: on line 14 in Report.razor: <li>@report.Title</li>

Comment: Try declaring the loop variable report as `Report` instead of `var` - see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately does this not fix my problem.

Comment: What is the actual error? - screenshots allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```cs
public class Report
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

but also a `Report.razor` page. That compiles to another `class Report`, and that one doesn't have a Title property.

```
  private List<Report> Reports = new();  // is a list of Blazor components
```

A quick fix is to rename your page to for instance `ReportPage.razor`. You can keep the `@page "/reports"` line so it won't affect anything else.

I use the *Page* suffix a lot, for precisely this reason.

Comment: Thank's a lot! It was my bad, the page naming was not sent.

Answer (score 0):

I would start a different approach based on an actual property which is not empty by default and change the razor file to wait for the async method to complete and show something else while the List is null:

```
@page "/reports"
@using BlazorApp.Shared
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
@attribute [Authorize]
@inject HttpClient Http

<PageTitle>Report</PageTitle>

<h1>Report</h1>
@if(Reports is not null) {
   <ul>
    @foreach (var report in Reports)
    {
        <li>@report.Title</li>
    }
    </ul>
}
//optional:
@if(Reports is not null && Reports.Count == 0) {
   <p>No Reports delivered.</p>
}

@code {

    private List<Report> Reports { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Reports = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Report>>("List/Report");
    }
}
```

Does this resolve your error atleast?

Comment: My mistake was the page naming. Thank's for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *Minimal Reproducible Example* based on the code you've provided.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Report</PageTitle>

<h1>Report</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var report in Reports)
    {
        <li>@report.Title</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {

    private List<Report> Reports = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.Reports = await ReportDataProvider.GetReportsAsListAsync();
        //Reports = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Report>>("List/Report");
    }

    public static class ReportDataProvider
    {
        public static async ValueTask<List<Report>> GetReportsAsListAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            return _reports.ToList();
        }

        public static async ValueTask<IEnumerable<Report>> GetReportsAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            return _reports.AsEnumerable();
        }

        private static List<Report> _reports = new List<Report>
        {
           new("HRH","Me","Shaun","Curtis"),
           new("Mr","You","Joe","Bloggs"),
        };

    }

    public class Report
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ReporterName { get; set; }
        public string ReporterLastname { get; set; }

        public Report() { }

        public Report(string title, string description, string reporterName, string reporterLastname)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Description = description;
            this.ReporterName = reporterName;
            this.ReporterLastname = reporterLastname;
        }
    }
}
```

As the error is in your Blazor code I've bypassed the controller and added a simple async data provider instead.

The code runs without a problem.  Therefore the problem is not in the code you've provided!

Comment: My mistake was the page naming. Thank's for your help!